# Showing Asp.Net.Core XUnit test results in Bamboo

Tags: .net-core, bamboo, xunit

I've just used a large part of the day figuring this one out.

Here is the problem: Being used to use MSTest in Bamboo and it works fine.

The first project using Asp.Net.Core, with XUnit tests comes along, and needs to be setup in Bamboo.

Bamboo doesn't support XUnit test result xml files.. Sigh...

What to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After upgrading to .Net Core SDK 1.1.1 final bits, this is much easier achived.

Executing the below will execute test, and generate a trx output.

```
dotnet test --logger trx
```

Alternatively to determine filename as well

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=myTestResults.trx"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling around this here is the recipe I used.

Execute tests as usual, output result to xml file

```
dotnet test .\MyProject\test\UnitTests -xml .\TestResults\UnitTests.xml
```

Run the output xml through an XSLT conversion and convert to MsTest trx format

```
$xml = Process-XSLT $PSScriptRoot\TestResults\UnitTests.xml $PSScriptRoot\BuildScripts\XUnitToMsTest.xlst
```

And here comes the culprit. Ensure the TRX xml files is written as UTF-8 - not an ascii file. Tried for hours to figure out why Bamboo wouldn't pick up the test files - until I realized this.

```
Out-File -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\TestResults\UnitTests.trx -InputObject $xml -Encoding UTF8
```

Sources:

XUnit to TRX : https://github.com/deloitte-solvas/XSLT-xUnit-To-Trx

ProcessXSLT : https://gist.github.com/wschwarz/5073004 (Had a few bugs)

Entire source to my own ProcessXSLT:

```
function Process-XSLT([string]$inputFile, [string]$xsl)
{
    $fileStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream($inputFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read);
    $fileStream.position = 0
    $xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($fileStream)
    $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
    $arglist = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
    $reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($output)
    $xslt.Load($xsl)
    $xslt.Transform($xml, $arglist, $output)
    $output.position = 0

    $transformed = [string]$reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    return $transformed
}
```

When all of the above is done correctly, all left to do is to add a MSTest Parser task to your Bamboo build, pointing at the TestResults folder.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/mstest-parser-289277057.html

I hope I save someone else a few minutes with this post.

Bamboo was absolutely no way near telling me the files was invalid - it just stated that no results could be picked up. :-)

Best regards
/Anders

Comment: This is for the 1.0.0 preview2 bits.